# Dudas sobre While y print en python

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python y tengo una duda acerca del bucle while y como hacer para imprimir todos los valores que se puedan general en el bucle

```py
punt = 0
usuario = int(input("Usuarios   "))
cont=1
while cont<=usuario:
    codigo = input("compo   ")
    if codigo == "A1":
        punt = 1
    elif codigo == "A2":
        punt  = 2
    elif codigo == "A3":
        punt  = 3
    elif codigo == "A4":
        punt  = 4
        break
    cont+=1
print(codigo)
print(punt)
```

la idea es que si por ejemplo tengo 2 usuarios en los prints me aparezca el
codigo y puntaje de cada uno, pero de esta manera solo logro que aparezca el
del ultimo que pasa por el bucle.

Comment: Pues mete esos `print()` dentro del bucle, que ahora mismo los tienes fuera y por tanto sólo se ejecutan una vez después de que el bucle haya terminado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Bien, lo que te esta pasando es bastante sencillo, se esta quedando siempre con el ultimo valor ya que a cada iteracion el valor se sobreescribe por que estas usando la misma variable, tienes que ir guardando las puntuaciones en una lista por ejemplo, o en un diccionario, al ser varios usuarios, y por lo tanto varias puntuaciones, tienes que guardar los valores en varias variables ... Por ejemplo:

  ```
  cantidad_de_usuarios = int(input('Introduce la cantidad de usuarios ==> '))
  i = 0
  usuarios = {} # esto es un diccionario
  while i < cantidad_de_usuarios:
      usuario = input(f'Introduce el nombre del usuario numero {i + 1} ==> ')
      puntuacion = input(f'Introduce la puntuacion de {usuario} ==> ')
      usuarios[usuario] = puntuacion
      i += 1
  print('\t\t Lista de usuarios !!')
  for i in usuarios.items(): 
      print(f'Nombre : {i[0]:10}, Puntuacion : {i[1]}')
  ```

-Besitos, Besitos, chao, chao !!